# I have a private published windows store app calling GetAppReceiptAsync(). How do I get the app receipt?

Tags: c#, c, uwp

I have a private published UWP windows store app that is calling following in an `async` method

```
 await CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync() .
```

It is not returning a receipt. How do I retrieve a user's current app receipt. I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases.

I am only working with the client application.

I only need to get the receipt from the client.

The UWP capabilities are only Internet(client) and AllJoyn.

I need to return a string or xaml receipt.

Comment: Please provide more information about your question. For example, what value did the method return when you call it? And have you actually made a purchase?

Comment: Besides, `The Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace is no longer being updated with new features. If your project targets Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) or a later release in Visual Studio (that is, you are targeting Windows 10, version 1607, or later), we recommend that you use the Windows.Services.Store namespace instead.`

Comment: How do I call current app without using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store? And the receipt the method is returning a string; also, I have purchased the app with a promotional code. The app is not free. The app has no in-app purchases. I am just trying to get the user's app receipt.

Comment: I am just trying to get the receipt like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases

Comment: `And the receipt the method is returning a string` I know it returns string. What the value did it return? The specific value.

Comment: No value because it hit an exception. I put it in a try and catch to stop it from crashing the app. I am using Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace. How do I use Windows.Services.Store namespace to get the receipt?

Comment: So, you described your issue incorrectly. You need to tell us you get exception. What’s the exception message?

Comment: I got this exception: 2145844844Not found (404). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80190194)

Comment: What do I need to do?

Comment: Please try Mattew's solution on this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1f84934-45a6-43c9-8b33-4f138ae38db5/loadlistinginformationasync-0x80190194-not-found-404?forum=wpsubmit). `Private audience is sending to private catalog and there is no retail availability in retail catalog. It seems the 404 error is by design in your case as this API is only working with retail catalog. Currently, you could submit an update and change the visibility option to public audience. If you need to restrict the availability,you could distribute your app through direct link+promotional code`

Comment: Ok, I am updating it with public visibility.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I am getting a receipt;but,static bool ValidateXml(XmlDocument receipt, X509Certificate2 certificate) is not working.

Comment: I got this exception: System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. I am following the article.

Comment: public static X509Certificate2 RetrieveCertificate(string certificateId) is working.ValidateXml(XmlDocument receipt, X509Certificate2 certificate) is not working.

Comment: Is the certificate Id from a receipt only needed to verify an app purchase for a specific app?